# get property of ts file in nodejs

Tags: node.js, angular

i want to acsess ts file's property in node.js file

here is my component file...

```
 EmailPage() {  
    let customObj = new mail();
    customObj.buyer =this.buyer,
    customObj.Category=this.getcat,
    customObj.Subcategory=this.getsubcat,
    customObj.Final_amt =this.Amt,
    customObj.PRDName =this.PRDName,
    customObj.total_month =this.total_month.toString();
    this.maildata.push(customObj);
  this.admin.sendMessage(this.maildata).subscribe(successCode => {
  this.statusCode = successCode;
},
```

here is my service..

```
sendMessage(body : mail[]):Observable<number> {
alert(JSON.stringify(body));
    return this.http.post("http://localhost:8080/sendmail", JSON.stringify(body),this.httpOptions)
    .pipe(map((success: any) => success))
```

my class file 'mail.ts' whose property i want in js file.

```
export class mail
{

        public buyer : string;
        public Category : string;
        public Subcategory : string;
        public Final_amt : string;
        public PRDName : string;
        public total_month : string;


}
```

and here is my node js file , i want buyer from mail.ts class file

```
app.post("/sendmail", (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body.buyer);
  let user = req.body.buyer;

  let final_amt = req.body.Final_amt;
  let mailOptions = {
    from: 'adworthised@gmail.com',
    to: 'moxnshah467@gmail.com',
    subject: "Email check",
    html:
```

Comment: is mail.ts a JSON file?  If so just use FS to read the file and parse it to an object.

Comment: i dont know how json file looks , but i posted it in my question , is it called json file ?if yes then how can i use FS to read the file?